# «Три Дня поля», с большой буквы День?

Tags: выбор-слов, прописная-строчная

*«Только в этом году мы организовали три Дня поля».*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, это какой-никакой праздник, хотя и неофицальный. Значит, его название пишется с прописной буквы. См. [§20. Названия праздников, народных движений, знаменательных дат](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/24.htm#%D0%B7_10) а также [Как пишутся названия праздников](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/74-rubric-87)?

Если считать это мероприятием, то подходит сказанное в [Справочнике издателя и автора](http://www.diamondsteel.ru/useful/handbook/3.html) (А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова):

Среди слов, выделяемых прописной буквой, различаются: 1) имена собственные в узком смысле этого слова и 2) наименования...
К наименованиям относятся названия учреждений, организаций, объединений, исторических эпох и событий, праздников, массовых ***мероприятий***...

Answer (score 0):

**Только в этом году мы организовали три Дня поля.**

**День поля** — профессиональный праздник работников сельского хозяйства. Он проводится в разных районах страны и имеет разные форматы.

Примеры:

1) **В девятнадцатый раз в Ступинском районе отметили День поля подмосковные аграрии.** День поля — праздник сельского труда В рамках «Дня поля» была организована выставка-ярмарка, где представлены все виды деятельности сельского хозяйства региона: от научно-исследовательских институтов с разработками по селекции зерновых и плодоовощных культур, многолетних трав, до производителей мясных, рыбных, молочных продуктов, меда, лекарственных трав, кондитерских и хлебобулочных изделий.

2) **Профессиональный форум аграриев "Всероссийский день поля"** прошел в России впервые за девять лет. В регионе создана современная площадка — Сибирский агропарк для демонстрации сельскохозяйственной техники и передовых аграрных технологий. Это одна из крупнейших в России выставочных площадок — на ней были представлены более 500 единиц техники различных компаний, в первую очередь – отечественных производителей.

Comment: Как я понял, только первое слово в названии праздника пишется с прописной буквы. Поэтому **Д**ень поля, но Всероссийский **д**ень поля.

Comment: У Розенталя: С прописной буквы пишется начальное слово неполного названия, которое употребляется в функции полного: Литературный музей (Государственный литературный музей),  Дом журналиста (Центральный Дом журналиста). Это правило можно, наверное, применить и к слову "день", так что варианты могут быть.http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/24.htm